# How to get number value with Decimal from DataReader

Tags: c#, int, decimal

According to the SQL queries below, I need to get a number value 2083.10, but when try to use the code to get int value from dbreader, it will be only 2083. the `demical` were gone.

```
string SQLCash = @"SELECT sum(t2.Cash-Change) AS Cash 
                        FROM dbFBHdr t1, dbFBCollection t2 
                        WHERE t1.Branch = t2.Branch 
                        AND t1.CashNo = t2.CashNo 
                        AND t1.CashDate >= '" + PDC.DateFrom + "' " +
                        "AND t1.CashDate <= '" + PDC.DateTo + "' " +
                        "AND t1.Status = 'CLOSED'";


FbCommand cmdCASH = new FbCommand(SQLCash, FbCon);
cmdCASH.ExecuteNonQuery();
FbDataReader readerCASH = cmdCASH.ExecuteReader();
while (readerCASH.Read() == true)
{
    if (readerCASH["Cash"].ToString() == "")
    {
        PDC.CASH = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        PDC.CASH += String.Format("{0:n}",readerCASH["Cash"]);
        PDC.TOCASH = readerCASH.GetInt32(readerCASH.GetOrdinal("Cash"));
    }
}
```

And This is the code which I use it to get Int value from SQL

```
PDC.TOCASH = readerCASH.GetInt32(readerCASH.GetOrdinal("Cash"));
```

Comment: If it's a decimal why you use `GetInt32` and not `GetDecimal`?

Comment: And use sql parameters. Concatenating string will lead you to errors one day

Comment: @Tim Schmelter 
Hi, Thank you ! When I change my code to **PDC.TOCASH = readerCASH.GetDecimal(readerCASH.GetOrdinal("Cash"));** , it come with an error **Connot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Comment: Because PDC.TOCASH is int. Change PDC.TOCASH to decimal...but why you want decimal if your PDC.TOCASH is int then...

Comment: I see ! It's succeeded ! Thank you so much ! For PDC.TOCASH is int is because I'm wrongly using it. Problem fix while I change to **public static decimal TOCASH = '0';**

Comment: @TeoLawrence: `int`(integer) is a type that has no decimal places, `decimal` is a type that can have decimal places. I'm just suprised that you haven't noticed it because you are already talking of `decimal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to Gets the value as a `Decimal` object, You need to use [`SqlDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal?view=netframework-4.7.2) method instead:

```
readerCASH.GetDecimal(readerCASH.GetOrdinal("Cash"));
```

Because the `GetInt32` method will get the value as a 32-bit signed integer. Also you need to change the `TOCASH`'s type to decimal. Also you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Something like this:

```
AND t1.CashDate >= @DateFrom 
yourCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", PDC.DateFrom);
//And other parameters also
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is better than `AddWithValue`. See this https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Thank you so much ! I changed to **GetDecimal** and problem fixed !

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `GetInt32` if you want to get value as `decimal`, use `GetDecimal`

```
PDC.TOCASH = readerCASH.GetDecimal(readerCASH.GetOrdinal("Cash"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I changed to **GetDecimal** and problem fixed !

Answer (score 0):

If you *not sure* to which *.Net* type will be mapped initial *RDBMS* one (e.g. `Number(16, 4) -> ?` will it be `Single`, `Double` or `Decimal`?) you can try *converting*:

```
   decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal(readerCASH["Cash"]);
```

Comment: I see, I will try also this method ^_^ Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting it to be without commas so it will be return as it is integer

```
PDC.CASH += String.Format("{0:n2}",readerCASH["Cash"]);
```

n2 means 2 digits after comma also i suggest you to use `{0:c2}` if you are working with currency

Comment: Thank you so much ! I changed to **GetDecimal** and problem fixed ! For using n2 instead of c2 is because of I don't want to present the currency sign on the windows form ~